# Using Outpan's JAVA API

Tags: java, android, api

I am having problems using the [Outpan JAVA API](https://github.com/johncipponeri/outpan-api-java) in my Android project. This API is also mentioned in the official Outpan website.

**My Progress till now-:**

- I downloaded the Outpan JAVA API from [here](https://github.com/johncipponeri/outpan-api-java/releases/), and extracted them.
- I copied the folder io inside the src folder (inside the downloaded folder) to home->AndroidStudioProjects->(Name of my project)->app->src->main->java **(I am using Android Studio on ubuntu)**.
- I copied the .jar file inside libs folder (inside the downloaded folder) to home->AndroidStudioProjects->(Name of my project)->app->libs folder.
- I opened my android studio project, which was created earlier (it scans for barcodes using the zxing library) and added these 2 lines to my import statements in the project-:


      import io.github.johncipponeri.outpanapi.OutpanAPI;
      import io.github.johncipponeri.outpanapi.OutpanObject;
- Next, I used the normal commands that were given in the github repository (that I have already mentioned earlier) along with the proper API Key (I have already registered on Outpan).
- Next I went to, the gradle file (Module: app) of my project, and added this line to the 'depedencies' section-:

      compile files('libs/org.json-20131017.jar')

So, when I tried to debug the app on my phone, the following errors came-:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidEmbedded201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidIntegration201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidLegacy201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
/home/ashutoshsaboo/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeScan/app/src/main/java/io/github/johncipponeri/outpanapi/OutpanAPI.java
Error:(33, 51) error: cannot find symbol method getEncoder()
/home/ashutoshsaboo/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeScan/app/src/main/java/io/github/johncipponeri/outpanapi/OutpanObject.java
Error:(44, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getNames(JSONObject)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.348 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

It would be better if you downloaded the API yourself from GitHub, as you will be able to have a look at all the files individually, because I can't paste the code of all the .java files here.

**Edit:**

Thanks @JohnCipponeri for your help. I downloaded the new updated version of your API, and placed the folder in your src folder in my app->src->main->java folder, and the .jar file in your libs folder in my app->libs folder. Also, I placed the "outpan-api-java-1.1.jar" in my app->libs folder, and added the following lines in my gradle file, under the dependencies section-:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/outpan-api-java-1.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

But sadly still two of the previous errors haven't been resolved. So, does my Android package name need to be of the same name as "**io.github.johncipponeri.outpanapi**", because currently my package name is different.

My Updated Message Dialog-:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidEmbedded201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidIntegration201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidLegacy201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
/home/ashutoshsaboo/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeScan/app/src/main/java/io/github/johncipponeri/outpanapi/OutpanAPI.java
Error:(48, 17) error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
/home/ashutoshsaboo/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeScan/app/src/main/java/io/github/johncipponeri/outpanapi/OutpanObject.java
Error:(44, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getNames(JSONObject)
Note: /home/ashutoshsaboo/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeScan/app/src/main/java/com/ashutoshsaboo/codescan/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 28.092 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Error is in this part of OutpanObject.java -:

```
public OutpanObject(JSONObject json) {
        this();

        this.gtin = json.getString("gtin");
        this.outpan_url = json.getString("outpan_url");

        if (!json.isNull("name"))
            this.name = json.getString("name");

        if (!json.isNull("attributes")) {
            JSONObject attrObject = json.getJSONObject("attributes");
            String[] attrs = JSONObject.getNames(attrObject);

            for (int a = 0; a < attrs.length; a++)
                this.attributes.put(attrs[a], attrObject.getString(attrs[a]));
        }

        if (!json.isNull("images")) {
            JSONArray imgs = json.getJSONArray("images");
            for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++)
                this.images.add(imgs.getString(i));
        }

        if (!json.isNull("videos")) {
            JSONArray vids = json.getJSONArray("videos");
            for (int i = 0; i < vids.length(); i++)
                this.videos.add(vids.getString(i));
        }
    }
```

Another Error is in this part of OutpanAPI.java-:

```
while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0)
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);

            jsonResult = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who created the Java wrapper for the Outpan API.

I faced the same problem. Android only supports up to Java 1.7 and the version of the JAR you're using was compiled using Java 1.8 and the 1.8 Base64 class.

If you download the latest version of the JAR from https://github.com/johncipponeri/outpan-api-java/releases/tag/v1.1 this problem is resolved.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**:

You can follow the following instructions to get it working as well. https://github.com/johncipponeri/outpan-api-java/blob/master/README.md#using-with-android-studio

You don't need to include your own copy of `org.json-20131017.jar` as it is packaged with the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, I am facing 2 of my previous errors, now as well. I have posted the updated changes, under the Edit section of my question. Please do have a look, and let me know the updated solution! Thanks!